# How to attach drawable-right onclick listener to a Toggle button Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, onclicklistener, android-drawable, togglebutton

I want to display a tool tip sort of information about a button to the user. I have set an image looking like "i" in the right of toggle button. 
[image]

now I want to set onClick Listener to that image. Can anyone help me with how to proceed.

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/fatigue"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="22dp"
android:background="@drawable/checkbutton"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textOn="Fatigue/Endurance"
    android:textOff="Fatigue/Endurance"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/info"
     android:drawableEnd="@drawable/info"

     />
```

Comment: might be better to just seperate the "info" button to be outside the toggle button to encourage info button re-use in other parts/designs of your app.

Comment: I want info button over the Toggle button. Only way I found was by setting image to drawable-right and then setting onclick listener for drawable right. But I am stuck at that.

Comment: Anyway You can [create custom compound view](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-compound-views-on-android--cms-22889).